# libGDX moving camera and an Image

Tags: android, libgdx

I currently have a game where there is a map that is 480x3200, and a person falling from the top. The camera follows the person, and there are platforms as the person falls. The platforms need to be touchable so I can rotate and move them during the game, so I made it an Image, when it was originally just a sprite.

When I changed it from a sprite to an Image, everything worked fine, except when the person falls (the camera starts moving down and follows the person), the platform also moves with the camera, so it looks like it's also falling. The platform should just stay in one spot, and not be moving with the camera so as the camera keeps moving down, the platform will eventually disappear from view.

Setting up the platform and adding it to the stage

```
@Override
public void show() {
    ...
    platform = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img_platform.png")));
    platform.setX(2);
    platform.setY(110);
    platform.setOrigin(platform.getWidth() / 2, platform.getHeight() / 2);

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    ....
    stage.addActor(platform);   
}
```

I've looked around the API, and can't determine whether the camera, stage, or Image needs to be changed, or something else that I haven't thought of. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

```
public WorldRenderer(FallDown game, SpriteBatch batch, World w) {
    this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT); 
    this.cam.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
    this.cam.setToOrtho(false, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    cam.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, 105, 0);
    stage = new Stage(480, 800, true);

    platformTexture = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img_platform.png")));
    platformTexture.setX(2);
    platformTexture.setY(100);
    platformTexture.setOrigin(platformTexture.getWidth() / 2, platformTexture.getHeight() / 2);
    ...

}

public void render(float delta) { 
    stage.addActor(platformTexture);
    moveCamera();
    ...
}

private void moveCamera() {
    if (Person.getPosition().y < cam.position.y) 
        cam.position.y = Person.getPosition().y;
    cam.update();
}

...
```

Comment: Move the stage.addActor(platform) to the show() method. You're currently re-adding the actor to the stage every render loop.

Comment: @Aert I added stage.addActor(platform) to show() and it gives me a NullPointerException. But I don't think adding to show() would work in my case because I also need collision detection on the platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an Image, I decided to just use a Sprite. It allows me do everything that I need to do, and I don't have the problem with the stage just being the current screen

Answer (score 1):

Normally this thing is achieved by setting your camera on actor (which is falling down) and moving your actor downwards. As the actor move down, camera will follow it keeping the platforms static.

Does this helps??

Comment: That's how I currently have my camera set up. I have a method that moves the camera down when the person's position gets to a certain point

Comment: Sry my bad. Actually you have to take 2 cameras. normally one is taken for game screen and another is taken in game world. Camera in game screen will not move . now draw your platforms using static camera and draw your other things using  moving camera. The idea is simple, all static things in game play will use static camera and dynamic things will use moving camera. For any reference check super jumper source. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos/superjumper

Comment: I kind of had it set up the way you're talking about before. I have a camera in my GameScreen that doesn't move and another moving camera in WorldRenderer (also where I originally drew my platform sprites). I moved my code over to WorldRenderer, and tried getting it to work, but the Image still doesn't stay in one spot. I edited my post and updated my current code. I appreciate the help so far